# Force display resolution on AMD card driver for TeamViewer with monitor unplugged

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, screen-resolution, teamviewer

We have HP microserver with AMD Radeon R5 card and Windows Server 2012 R2. There is no monitor plugged in. Connecting with RDP works well since AMD driver is replaced by RDP driver and resolution is OK.

However using VNC or TeamViewer, resolution remains 640x480 with no option to be changed. The problem is similar to [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/531729/teamviewer-remote-computer-640x480-screen), but none of the answers is applicable to my situation.

We need to enable our supplier to be able to connect with TeamViewer and now it is impossible. I have checked many solutions available, even I have disabled radeon driver, installed mirror graphics driver, but nothing helped.
After uninstalling AMD driver the Microsoft Basic Display Adapter shows error code 43 and the resolution remains stuck at 640x480.

Is there a way how to force resolution for TeamViewer like it does RDP display driver?

Comment: Try https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_10-other_settings/how-to-enable-a-fake-second-display-in-windows-10/3c02e2ee-cade-4916-be46-390e59ea2a04?auth=1

Comment: Or https://www.amazon.com/dp/B06XT1Z9TF/ref=cm_sw_r_cp_awdb_t1_ImtOAbW62SZAS

Comment: Thanks, but I have already seen both of them.The first one does not work and the second one is actually plugging in a fake monitor. But some other software solution must exist.